# State computed properties not accesible in other computed properties?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, store, computed-properties

In vuex store how can I access a computed property inside other computed properties (getters) ?

This is how my state object looks like:

```
state: {
  a: 5
},

getters: {

  propA(state){
    return state.a; // ok
  },

  propB(state){
    return state.propA; // undefined
  }

}
```

If I try to access `state.propA` from `propB` I get undefined...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getters` are passed as the second argument, so it would be:

```js
propB (state, getters) {
  return getters.propA;
}
```

See https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#getters

Whereas components smash all properties together so that `this.blah` might come from `data`, `computed` or `props` the Vuex store keeps the different parts separate so you always have to be explicit about exactly what you're accessing.

Comment: thanks. do you know if it's expensive to call these getters multiple times? I mean does the function run every time, or do they work like computed properties from components ?

Comment: @Alex `getters` work just like computed properties and cache their return value until their dependencies change. This is explained here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Comment: But it doesn't apply to getters accessed as getters? Because on that page it implies that they are cached only if they are accessed as properties

Comment: @Alex They are cached no matter how you access them. The section on `Method-Style Access`, if that's what you mean, is trying to explain something quite nuanced. Specifically, there's a trick whereby a getter returns a function and that function can then be invoked, giving the illusion that the getter is being called as a method. While the return value of a getter is cached, any function it returns is not itself a getter, so no caching is applied to that function. You can use a bit of console logging to explore the caching yourself if you have any doubts.